# memset fails to set a string to zero and goes into segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, memset

I'm doing an exercise about UDP sockets in C. When the client sends a specific message (e.g hi) the server has to send "Nice to meet you". If no standard reply is found the server sends "No suitable reply". My problem is that `memset` fails if I try to return the reply like this:

```
return "No suitable reply";
```

and it doesn't if I return the reply in this way:

```
char* foo = malloc(sizeof(char*));
memset(foo, 0, strlen(ses));
memcpy(foo, "No suitable reply", 17);
return foo;
```

I tried to google a solution to this and I found [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/problem-with-memset-and-char-pointer-757174/) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memset-c-example/), but they don't seem to address my problem (I first thought that memset doesn't work on a string declared like `char string[] = "something"` but in the second example they use memset on a static string).

Here is the whole code (the memset I'm talking about is right at the end):

```
   /*
    Alessandro Dussin 5AI
    2018-17-11
    Write a program to handle a single UDP "connection"
    */

//Standard libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Sockets libraries and connection ahndling
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

//Read/write ops on file descriptors
#include <unistd.h>
//String ops
#include <string.h>

#include <assert.h>
void chopN(char *str, size_t n)
{
    assert(n != 0 && str != 0);
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len)
        return;  // Or: n = len;
    memmove(str, str+n, len - n + 1);
}

//Required by the exercise. Given a certain word or phrase, reply with a specific string
char* switchreply(char* str){
    //Extracts the word or phrase (Basically removes the "/command " word)
    chopN(str, strlen("/stdreply "));
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < strlen(str); i++){
        if(str[i] == '\n'){
            str[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(strcmp(str, "ciao") == 0){
        return "ciao anche a te!";
    }
    else if(strcmp(str, "I hate you") == 0){
        return "I hate you too!";
    }
    return "";
}


char* stdreply(char *str){

    char* tmp = malloc(sizeof(char)*128);
    int i = 0;
    //printf("Entered stdreply... str at the start of the func: %s\n", str);
    for(; i < strlen(str); i++){
        tmp[i] = str[i];
        //printf("tmp: %s\n", tmp); //DEBUG
        if(strcmp(tmp, "/echo ") == 0){ // if(strcmp() == 0) is necessary because
                                        //otherwise 0 would be interpreted as FALSE
            //printf("Echo detected\n"); //DEBUG
            chopN(str, strlen("/echo "));
            str[strlen(str)] = '\0';
            return str;
        }
        else if(strcmp(tmp, "/stdreply ") == 0){
            //printf("I got into the else if\n"); //DEBUG
            char* tmpreply = calloc(strlen(str), sizeof(char*));
            tmpreply = switchreply(str);
            //printf("tmpreply: %s\n", tmpreply);
            str = malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(tmpreply));
            memcpy(str, tmpreply, strlen(tmpreply));
            //str[strlen(str)] = '\0'; //DEBUG
            //printf("str: %s\n", str); //DEBUG
            return str;
        }
        else if(strcmp(tmp, "/TODO") == 0){
            char* ses = malloc(sizeof(char*));
            memset(ses, 0, strlen(ses));
            memcpy(ses, "work in progress", 17);
            return ses;
        }

    }
    return "No suitable reply";

    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: ./server port");
        exit(0);
    }

    int serverfd;
    serverfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if(bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
        perror("Bind() error: ");
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    //"UDP message receiver" variables declarations
    int bytes; //Reads how many bytes the funcion recvfrom has read
    struct sockaddr_in from;

    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char*)); //String to which save the client message
    memset(buffer, 0, strlen(buffer)); //and set it to zero

    socklen_t fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    const char stdrep[] = "Message Received: "; //This string will always be
                                                //printed upon receiving a message
    char* reply = malloc(sizeof(char*)); //This is where the return value of
                                        //stdreply() will be stored
    memset(reply, 0, strlen(reply)); //and set it zero

    //This while will keep "listening" for udp messages
    while((bytes = recvfrom(serverfd, buffer, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen)) > 0){
        //From teacher's example. Write to stdout
        write(1, stdrep, strlen(stdrep));
        write(1, buffer, bytes);
        //Detect a basically empty string (if the client has pressed only enter)
        if(buffer[0] == '\n'){
            bytes = sendto(serverfd, "You pressed only enter!\n", 18, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, fromlen);
        }

        //Act according to the client message
        reply = stdreply(buffer);
        bytes = sendto(serverfd, reply, strlen(reply), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, fromlen);
        if (bytes  < 0){
            perror("sendto: ");
            fflush(stderr);
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
        memset(reply, 0, strlen(reply)); //The seg fault happens right here
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char*));` allocates space the size of a `char *`, which is almost surely less than you need to accommodate a copy of `"No suitable reply"`.  And you need **18** bytes for that, by the way, not 17, because you need to account for the terminator.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem to work. You see, the seg fault happens only if `reply` has a string which has been returned like this`return "something";`, otherwise it works.

Comment: I did not say that was the only problem, but it certainly *is* a problem.  You've presented much more code than we generally want to see.  If you reduce it to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, then you are more likely to get an actual answer.

Comment: `malloc` + `memset` is asking for `calloc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of problems in the code you are posting.

1. As @JonBolinger already noted, `sizeof(char*)` returns the size in bytes of a pointer to a char. On Intel platforms this will be either 4 or 8, depending on whether you are running on 32-bit or 64-bit. (So you end up allocating buffers of 4 or 8 bytes)
2. You consistently try to clear your dynamically-allocated buffers with `memset()`. `malloc()` will return memory filled with garbage, and you indicate how many bytes to clear by using `strlen()` on the returned buffer. `strlen()` will scan the buffer until it finds the first 0 character to compute the string's length.  **Since the buffer is filled with garbage, this can easily give you a value outside of the boundaries of your memory block and you will end up corrupting memory.**
3. Every call to `malloc()` should be matched to a `free()` call, otherwise you will leak memory. This is especially important if your program is long-running.

When you are working with temporary local strings (strings that are not returned to the caller), it is very common practice to use a local char array instead of malloc().  This way, the buffer gets allocated on the stack and will be released automatically when your function exits scope. Just be sure to use 'safe' string functions like `strncpy()` that will accept as a parameter the length of the buffer, to avoid overwrites.

```
void Example(char* anotherString ) {
    char tmpString[256];   // this will create a local buffer with capacity of 256 bytes
    strncpy(tmpString, anotherString, sizeof(tmpString));  // copy string, without risk of overflowing the buffer
}
```

Warning: **NEVER** attempt to return a local temporary buffer as a result, remember that it will no longer exist when the function exits and although the returned value may initially have meaningful results, they will certainly be destroyed as soon as you call another function. Instead of this, another common practice when you need a string return value, instead of returning a string allocated with `malloc()` -that would need to be released with `free()` - you pass a local buffer that will hold the result as a parameter, like this:

```
void func1() {
    char result[256];
    func2(result, 256);
    // after calling, result will carry "a returned string"
}

void func2(char* result, size_t bufferLen) {
    strncpy(result, "a returned string", bufferLen);
}
```

I think your code would benefit greatly if you can transform it to using this style where applicable.

Answer (score 0):

```
reply = stdreply(buffer);
```

This does not copy a string.  It overwrites the pointer with a different one, losing the original pointer.

```
memset(reply, 0, strlen(reply));
```

This would clear the string if it were allocated with malloc.  If it is a constant string like "No suitable reply" then it may be read-only, so it generates a segfault.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I'm going to try it now. I'm starting to find a lot more problems in my stdreply() function now and I'll update my question with what will (hopefully) be useful information as soon as I fix my code.